# Multiple operations on a single value in SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to create a column that will apply to different interests to it based on how much each customer's cumulative purchases are. Not sure but I was thinking that I'd need to use a do while statement but entirely sure. :S
This is what I got so far but I don't know how to get it to perform two operations on one value. Such that, it will apply one interest rate until say, 4000, and then apply the other interest rate to the rest above 4000.

```
data cards;
set sortedccards;
by Cust_ID;
if first.Cust_ID then cp=0;
cp+Purchase;
if cp<=4000 then cb=(cp*.2);
if cp>4000 then cb=(cp*.2)+(cp*.1);
format cp dollar10.2 cp dollar10.2;
run;
```

What I'd like my output to look like.

[image]

Comment: Edit the question and replace the image with text of the actual data

Comment: Sorry that I didn't do it before you helped me out! I was asleep when you asked. Thanks for the assistance though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to also track the prior cumulative purchase in order to detect when a purchase causes the cumulative to cross the threshold (or breakpoint) $4,000.  Breakpoint crossing purchases would be split into pre and post portions for different bonus rates.

Example:

Program flow causes retained variable `pcp` to act like a `LAG`ged variable.

```
data have;
input id $ p; 
datalines;
C001 1000
C001 2300
C001 2000
C001 1500
C001  800
C002 6200
C002  800
C002  300
C003 2200
C003 1700
C003 2500
C003  600
;

data want;
  set have;
  by id;

  if first.id then do;
     cp = 0;
    pcp = 0;  retain pcp; /* prior cumulative purchase */
  end;

  cp + p;   /* sum statement causes cp to be implicitly retained */

  * break point is 4,000;

  if (cp > 4000 and pcp > 4000) then do;
    * entire purchase in post breakpoint territory;
    b = 0.01 * p;
  end;
  else 
  if (cp > 4000) then do;
    * split purchase into pre and post breakpoint portions;
    b = 0.10 * (4000 - pcp) + 0.01 * (p - (4000 - pcp));
  end;
  else do;
    * entire purchase in pre breakpoint territory;
    b = 0.10 * p;
  end;

  * update prior for next implicit iteration;
  pcp = cp;
run;
```

Comment: Wow. I'm new to SAS and learned so much just reading this! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fairly straightforward solution which is not optimized but works.  We calculate the cumulative purchases and cumulative bonus at each step (which can be done quite simply), and then calculate the current period bonus as cumulative bonus minus previous cumulative bonus.

This is assuming that the percentage is 20% up to $4000 and 30% over $4000.

```
data have;
   input id $ period MMDDYY10. purchase;
   
datalines;
C001 01/25/2019 1000
C001 02/25/2019 2300
C001 03/25/2019 2000
C001 04/25/2019 1500
C001 05/25/2019 800
C002 03/25/2019 6200
C002 04/25/2019 800
C002 05/25/2019 300
C003 02/25/2019 2200
C003 03/25/2019 1700
C003 04/25/2019 2500
C003 05/25/2019 600
;
run;

data want (drop=cumul_bonus);
   set have;
   by id;
   
   retain cumul_purchase cumul_bonus;
   
   if first.id then call missing(cumul_purchase,cumul_bonus);
   
   ** Calculate total cumulative purchase including current purchase **;
   cumul_purchase + purchase;
   ** Calculate total cumulative bonus including current purchase **;
   cumul_bonus = (0.2 * cumul_purchase) + ifn(cumul_purchase > 4000, 0.1 * (cumul_purchase - 4000), 0);
   ** Bonus for current purchase = total cumulative bonus - previous cumulative bonus **;
   bonus = ifn(first.id,cumul_bonus,dif(cumul_bonus));
   
   format period MMDDYY10.
          purchase cumul_purchase bonus DOLLAR10.2
          ;
   
run;

proc print data=want;
```